# What's the equivalent of cout for output to strings?

Tags: c++, standard-library

I should know this already but... `printf` is to `sprintf` as `cout` is to `____`? Please give an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Of course C++ streams don't use format-specifiers like C's `printf()`-type functions; they use [`manipulators`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Example, as requested:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

std::string stringify(double x, size_t precision)
{
    std::ostringstream o;
    o << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << x;
    return o.str();
}

int main()
{
    assert(stringify(42.0, 6) == "42.000000");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ streams *can* handle format specifiers, with appropriate help. See [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/format/doc/format.html).

Comment: @Rob: The "appropriate help" is important. They do not out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::ostringstream
```

You can use this to create something like the Boost lexical cast:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string ToString( const T & t ) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
}
```

In use:

```
string is = ToString( 42 );      // is contains "42"
string fs = ToString( 1.23 ) ;   // fs contains something approximating "1.23"
```

Comment: You could at least provide a [link to the reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/) when trying to defeat the 30 character limit.

Comment: @Tim I'm under no obligation to provide anything here, particularly when as the OP says he should know it already. Think of my answer as a reminder.

Comment: The limit is there to encourage you to write something intelligent, not to evade it with useless bumf.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostringstream s;
    s.precision(3);
    s << "pi = " << fixed << 3.141592;
    cout << s.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
pi = 3.142
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream sout;
    sout << "Hello " << 10 << "\n";

    const std::string s = sout.str();
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to clear the stream for reuse, you can do

```
sout.str(std::string());
```

Also look at the [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/format/doc/format.html) library.

Answer (score -1):

You have a little misunderstanding for the concept of cout. cout is a stream and the operator << is defined for any stream. So, you just need another stream that writes to string in order to output your data. You can use a standard stream like std::ostringstream or define your own one.

So your analogy is not very precise, since cout is not a function like printf and sprintf

Comment: He didn't ask for a function; he used an analogy.

Comment: +1 rather than coming up with a doubtful answer that doesn't really fit (how is "ostringstream" an object like "cout"? printf and sprintf are both functions), this answer explains the mistake in the analogy the questioner tried to make up! EDIT: Sadly, he removed his notes on the flaw in the analogy.