# C++ how to use a variable in a string

Tags: c++, string

The following code doesn't work:

```
string currency;
currency = "EURUSD";

system("lynx -dump 'http://somesite.com/q?s="+currency+"=X' > file.txt");
```

How do I use `currency` inside this line of C++'s `system()` call?

This is my error:

```
Error value:
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:84: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int system(const char*)’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 890ms)
```

In PHP I use `.` to join strings, but in C++ I am not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
string currency;
currency = "EURUSD";
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "lynx -dump 'http://somesite.com/q?s=" << currency << "=X' > file.txt";
system(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: +1: Better than my answer as this will work with "variables" other than `std::string` (as long as they have the appropriate `operator <<()`defined. This also allows [formatting via manipulators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5918156/78845).

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::c_str()` will give you a `char*` (const'd somehow) that you can use in C string functions. But you should consider creating a `std::string` that contains the full command first.

Comment: What do you mean by const'd *somehow*?

Comment: @chris: There's 3 different ways to const a pointer to a non-void type. I can't recall which way is used here.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, It returns `const char *`.

Comment: @chris: Well there we go then.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `+` a `std::string` to a `char []`. Although you can `+` a `char []` to a `std::string`.

I suggest using `std::string`s and getting the `const char*` just for the call to `system()`:

```
string const currency = "EURUSD";
string const command_line = "lynx -dump 'http://somesite.com/q?s=" + currency + "=X' > file.txt";

system(command_line.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

```
std::string currency("EURUSD");
std::string command("lynx -dump 'http://somesite.com/q?s="+currency+"=X' > file.txt")
system(command.c_str());
```

Comment: Johnsyweb was faster typing ;-)

Comment: `command.c_street`? You've been watching too much Coronation Street.

Comment: Frickin' mobile's auto-completion ;-)